# How to implode data in Opencart?

Tags: mysql, opencart, implode

I want to implode platform data with commas, like: Windows, Mac, Linux.

I've tried different options, but still have not found a solution. So i have a question how to implode that data which i get with this code?

```
<?php

$this->load->model('catalog/platform');

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT p2p.platform_id, p.parent_id FROM "
. DB_PREFIX . "platform p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_platform p2p
ON p.platform_id=p2p.platform_id WHERE product_id='" . $product_id . "' AND parent_id=0");

$prodplatforms = $query->rows;

foreach($prodplatforms as $prodplatform){

    $platform_id = $prodplatform['platform_id'];
    $platform_info = $this->model_catalog_platform->getPlatform($platform_id);
    $caturl = (HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/platform&path=' . $platform_id);
    $str = $platform_info['name'];

        echo '<a href="' . $caturl . '">' . $str . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? do you want to concatenate links and store in a variable instead of echoing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need just a little edit - instead of `$str = $platform_info['name'];` do this:

```
// ...
$prodplatforms = $query->rows;

$platforms = array();

foreach($prodplatforms as $prodplatform){
    $platform_id = $prodplatform['platform_id'];
    $platform_info = $this->model_catalog_platform->getPlatform($platform_id);
    $caturl = (HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/platform&path=' . $platform_id);
    $platforms[] = $platform_info['name'];
}

echo '<a href="' . $caturl . '">' . implode(', ', $platforms) . '</a>';
```

But now looking at the code I guess You just want to have each platform name link to it's platform URL...

Looking at Your code I guess that You are doing this all within a template file. Maybe You just put the code together from Your controller, model and template - which would be OK, but in case You are truly doing this all within a template, please split the code to the layers:

**controller**:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/platform');
$prodplatforms = $this->model_catalog_platform->getPlatforms($product_id);

$this->data['platforms'] = array();

foreach($prodplatforms as $prodplatform){
    $platform_id = $prodplatform['platform_id'];
    $platform_info = $this->model_catalog_platform->getPlatform($platform_id);
    $caturl = (HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/platform&path=' . $platform_id);
    $this->data['platforms'][] = '<a href="' . $caturl . '">' . $platform_info['name'] . '</a>';
}
```

**model** (`catalog/model/catalog/platform.php`):

```
public function getPlatforms($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p2p.platform_id, p.parent_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "platform p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_platform p2p ON p.platform_id=p2p.platform_id WHERE product_id='" . $product_id . "' AND parent_id=0");

    return $query->rows;
}
```

**view template**:

```
<div><?php echo implode(', ', $platforms); ?></div>
```